# Extract only specified keyword/link from source code using REGEXP

Tags: html, regex, imacros

First this is the imacro script I made:

```
VERSION BUILD=11.1.495.5175   
TAB T=1  
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS  
SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.2  
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES  
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"(youtube. com/([^']+))" EXTRACT=$1  
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"(dailymotion. com/embed/video/([^']+)info=0)" EXTRACT=$1 
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}
```

I managed to make it work somehow but running this code gives me text of something like this

```
<br> <a class="button red xLarge"
href="//www.dailymotion. com/embed/video/sample29831"
target="_blank"><span>DMOTION</span></a><br> <a class="button red
xLarge" href="//www.dailymotion. com/embed/video/sample2d9sa"
target="_blank"><span>DMOTION</span></a><br> <a class="button red
xLarge" href="//www.youtube. com/sample3hjdaks"
target="_blank"><span>youtube</span></a>
```

what I want to do is only collect:

```
dailymotion. com/embed/video/sample29831 
dailymotion. com/embed/video/sample2d9sa
youtube. com/sample3hjdaks
```

How will I be able to achieve this using REGEXP?

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will likely work:

```
(?<=href="\/\/).*(?<=")
```

Comment: thanks that reduced the number of codes thats not necessary, i've got a workaround of it by making macro from notepad++.

Comment: However, is my answer the correct answer to your question did I misunderstand your question?